# Parsing docker images with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Okay so I'm trying to parse some docker images using regular expression.
So, I have a list of strings, each one looks like this :

bamos/openface       latest       62d1673065e8       12 weeks ago       1.941 GB

where

- bamos/openface --> Repository
- latest --> Tag
- 62d1673065e8  --> Image ID
- 12 weeks ago --> Created
- 1.941 GB --> Size

What I'm trying to do is check if that string contains both "bamos/openface" AND "Latest" in it. So basically I need to check for a specific repository and it's tag. If the string does contain them, then I must retrieve the (Image ID) in a separate string

How can I setup my pattern matching for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the strings in your pattern to test a match, and capture image ID in a group like this:

```
^bamos\/openface\h+latest\h+([a-z0-9]+)
```

[See the regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Xu5Q1B/2)

Your image id will be available in group 1 if the string is a match. See below an example of code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String regex = "^bamos\\/openface\\h+latest\\h+([a-z0-9]+)";
String string = "bamos/openface       latest       62d1673065e8       12 weeks ago       1.941 GB\n"
     + "other/repository       latest       22d1673065e8       12 weeks ago       1.941 GB\n"
     + "bamos/openface       previous       77d1673065e8       12 weeks ago       1.941 GB";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

This example outputs the image id for the first

[See the Java code demo](https://ideone.com/foD5QR)

Comment: it's perfect. thank you @Niitaku so much! and the regex101 website is such an amazing place to learn from about regular expressions.

Comment: @Acidburn73 It is. :) But be carefull: here, using just a `if (matcher.find())` works well because there is only one possible match. if you test your lines all at once, consider using a `while`. I'm updating my answer.